# How to make a button event in pure xaml

Tags: xaml

I have this code

```
<Image Name="LightOn_BMP" Source="Res/LightOn.bmp" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="10" />
    <Image Name="LightOff_BMP" Source="Res/LightOFF.bmp" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="10" />

    <Button Canvas.Left="215" Canvas.Top="150" Click="PowerOn">
        <Image Name="SwitchDown_BMP" Source="Res/SwitchDown.bmp"  />
    </Button>
    <Button Canvas.Left="215" Canvas.Top="150" Click="PowerOff">
        <Image Name="SwtichUp_BMP" Source="Res/SwitchUp.bmp"  />
    </Button>
```

And I want in pure XAML to make the PowerOn event to change so that LightOn.bmp is visible and LightOff.bmp is hidden and hide the Switchdown.bmp picture/button

Then I should be able to figure out how to make the event for the PowerOff

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't. The whole idea behind WPF is that you should separate behavior from display. So, at least without making some crazy black magic, you won't be able to change the state of the Image object (visible to false).